How to make 2 emulators ping each other in Android Studio?
I have been doing some tinkering about Android emulators, but now I really have to put both of them to the same network with the host. The port forwarding technique shown here unfortunately did not work since they are getting connected on a host level, they cannot send packets directly to each other.
How else would you emulate Android devices where you need to have them on the same LAN with the host. Let's say the host is in network 192.168.1.0/24, so I want Android devices to get IP addresses via the DHCP of the gateway on the same network.
I was thinking about bridging the network adapter, but I haven't got far with this solution.
